# Node.js object-oriented controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been experimenting with the Express Node.js framework. On the face of it, the approach of passing functions to `app.VERB` methods seems unusual. In other frameworks I've used (in languages other than javascript), you create a single handler class for each url pattern, with methods representing different HTTP verbs. One advantage is the ability to bundle common functionality in methods of superclasses.

I've tried to replicate this in node, but I'm interested in feedback on whether this seem like a good approach.

(I realise that the naming of "as_view" doesn't make much sense - I just named it that way because I'm used to django, where the term "view" is used to refer to something akin to a controller rather than a template.)

```
function Controller(verbs) {
    for (verb in verbs) {
        this[verb] = verbs[verb];
    }
}
Controller.prototype.as_view = function() {
    var dispatcher = function(req, res) {
        var verb = req.method.toLowerCase();
        this[verb](req, res);
    };
    return dispatcher.bind(this);
};

var pageone = new Controller({

    get: function(req, res) {
        res.send("Get request");
    },

    post: function(req, res) {
        res.send("Post request");
    }
});

....

app.all('/pageone', pageone.as_view()); 
....
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at express.js version 4. There is a function called `route` in the router. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.route

Answer (score 3):

This looks good to me,

- As you mentioned, `as_view` stands out a bit, but I see where you are coming from
- I am not sure why you do not declare `GET` and `POST`, then you do not need to use `toLowerCase()`, are you worried the caller will now uppercase the verbs?
- You should think about error handling, you should have some framework for it

All in all, I would still suggest that learning and using Express.js might be worth it.